# Time in milliseconds in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this logging that I built part of it is to time the entire process from start to finish. In this script we are unzipping, pulling data and merging and rezipping these files. Imported default_timer from timeit as shown below. All of the processes are timed as is the entire time it takes to run the script. The out put in the log is this -1.207415584403293e-06 for the time it takes to rezip and I cannot figure out how to get it out of scientific notation and display it as either milliseconds or microseconds. Any ideas? The coding is as below:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
fullstart = start
```

this is the import and call for the timer at the beginning and the coding at the end is as follows:

```
end = timer()
logger.info("Total time in sec "+str(end - fullstart))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is [output formatting](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php).  Below, I've used the oldest version; I suggest that you read the documentation and pick the form you like best.
I multiplied by a million to get microseconds, and then used a simple float format specification to print something more readable.  I'll let you replace the **print** with a logging command.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
fullstart = start

for i in range(100000):
    pass

end = timer()
print("Total time : %.1f ms" % (1000 * (end - fullstart)))
```

Output:

```
Total time : 7.3 ms
```

Comment: Yes, I over-designed.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply this number by 1,000 in order to get the mili-seconds (1/1000) time difference, or multiply by 1,000,000 and you will get the micro-seconds (1/1000000) time difference.
The `default_timer` returns the time in microsecond.

For more information: [default_timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer).